# What is the purpose of CTRL+T and CTRL+SHIFT+T in all modern text editors?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

I have seen this in countless text editors, including Visual Studio.

Can anyone explain where is this useful for?

So far I have only managed to break my undo/redo chain with it countless times. I tried to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> but instead I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Today I noticed there is even worse shortcut key in Visual Studio 2008: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> - it's similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> but actually much worse:

```
int some_funny(){
    return stuff;
}
void hehe(){
    return haha;
}
bool finished;
```

Becomes (after dozen of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> hits):

```
some_funny return(){
    stuff void;
}
hehe return(){
    haha bool;
}
finished int;
```

I don't understand how this can possibly be useful for anybody.

Comment: This is stupid indeed, but doesn't quite fit the website's topic.

Comment: Its use seems to extend only to the point of prompting this question... that said, I would say it is debatable as to whether or not it is useful

Comment: This question relates directly to a function of a common IDE and is therefore on topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

**T** stands for **T**ranspose.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> transposes the characters around the cursor.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> transposes the words around the cursor.

Comment: i didnt ask what it does, i asked what is it useful for.

Comment: It's useful for transposing characters.  (eg, if you make a tyop)

Comment: It's useful for doing what it does.

Comment: How is that useful? i mean, if i make a typo, its *rarely* only two characters swapped places, i will just erase and rewrite, rather than find out its actually two chars swapped places and move my cursor in middle of them... thats a bit too much time consuming to scan for such things, easier to just rewrite. not to mention when it moves the cursor after im done, it becomes even less useless (what if i press TWICE in accident...)

Comment: I accidentally transpose characters somewhat frequently.  If you really don't like it, feel free to unbind or replace the shortcut in options.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are a c++ loony and you insist on formatting satements such as

```
if(variable == 2)
```

as

```
if(2 == variable)
```

Selecting "variable" and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> will swap the two.

So not completely useless.

Comment: why would anyone want to use the latter...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(programming)#Equality_operator

Comment: ive done that mistake maybe twice in my whole life. not a reason to make code unreadable.